# why we use hadoop mapreduce for data process ? why not do on local machine?

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, mapreduce, bigdata

I am confused that, I try to take probability like one million random numbers. and I try both ways using MapReduce in google dataProc and also run python script on spyder to do the same. but the faster was the local machine. then why we use Mapreduce for that?
there is below codes which i use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Random Number Generating
x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=1000000)

counts = Counter(x)
total = sum(counts.values())
d1 = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
grad = d1.keys()
prob = d1.values()
#print(str(grad))
#print(str(prob))
#bins = 20
plt.hist(prob,bins=20, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
#plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')
plt.xlabel('Probability')
plt.ylabel('Number Of Students')
plt.title('Histogram of Students Grade')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""mapper.py"""
import sys

# Get input lines from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    #line = line.strip()

    # Split it into tokens
    #tokens = line.split()

    #Get probability_mass values
    for probability_mass in line:
        print("None\t{}".format(probability_mass))
        #print(str(probability_mass)+ '\t1')
        #print('%s\t%s' % (probability_mass, None))
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""reducer.py"""
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(float)

# Get input from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    #line = line.strip()

    # skip empty lines
    if not line:
        continue  

    # parse the input from mapper.py
    k,v = line.split('\t', 1)
    counts[v] += 1
total = (float(sum(counts.values())))
#total = sum(counts.values())
probability_mass = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
print(probability_mass)
```

Comment: Hadoop should only be used when your dataset is too large to process on a single machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadoop is used for storing and processing big data. In Hadoop data is stored on inexpensive commodity servers that run as clusters. It is a distributed file system allows concurrent processing and fault tolerance. Hadoop MapReduce programming model is used for faster storage and retrieval of data from its nodes.

Google Dataproc is Apache Hadoop on Cloud. When volume is huge single machine is not sufficient to process Map/Reduce. 
1 Million is small volume.

Comment: "1 Million" is not a volume, it's only a number. "1 million 10GB files" is a proper volume as it denotes the total size and "weight"